# Páginas HTML: preencher formulário e fazer estes dados aparecerem em uma 2ª página ambas HTML, mas como?

Tags: javascript, html, front-end

O que tenho que fazer parece simples, mas não estou conseguindo.

Preciso preencher um formulário e ao clicar no botão salvar ele deverá mostrar outra página com estes mesmos dados que cadastrei na página anterior. Faço isso somente com HTML e JavaScript?

Estou usando método GET.

Abaixo seguem códigos

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Exercício 01 - Exibição de Formulário</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>*** Formulário de Cadastro ***</h1>
    <hr />
  </div>

  <p><i><h3>Todos os campos com * são de preenchimento obrigatório!</h3></i></p>

  <form action="exe01 - informacoes Cadastrais.html" method="GET" onsubmit="javascript: return salvarDados()">
    <label><b>Nome:</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="txtNome" value="" /> *
    <br /> <br />

    <label><b>Sobrenome:</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="txtSobrenome" value="" /> *
    <br /><br />

    <label><b>CPF:</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="txtCpf" value="" /> *
    <br /> <br />

    <label><b>Telefone:</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="txtTelefone" value="" /> *
    <br /> <br />

    <label><b>E-mail:</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="txtEmail" value=""> *
    <br /> <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Salvar" />
  </form>

  <!-- CÓDIGO JAVASCRIPT -->
  <script>
    function salvarDados() {
      var nome = document.getElementById("txtNome").value;
      var sobrenome = document.getElementById("txtSobrenome").value;
      var cpf = document.getElementById("txtCpf").value;
      var telefone = document.getElementById("txtTelefone").value;
      var email = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;

      var dados = "Nome: " + nome + "Sobrenome: " + sobrenome +
        "CPF: " + cpf + "Telefone: " + telefone + "E-mail: " + email;

      return true;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: creio que você tem que usar PHP

Comment: opa, certo. vou tentar tbm, vlw

Answer (score 1):

Você podes usar **localStorage** ou **sessionStorage** da API [Web Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API_pt_br)

Para isto basta filtrar seu form salvando os dados **"requeridos"** e armazenar em `JSON` na página "seguinte" basta verificar se a entrada existe e recupera-lá.

**exemplo: (página 1)**

```
<!-- HTML Fragment -->
<form id="first-form" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input id="first-name" type="text" required>
    <input id="last-name" type="text" required>
    <input id="cpf" type="text" required>
    <input id="tel" type="tel" required>
    <input id="mail" type="email" required>
    <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>

<script>
    // get form
    var form = document.getElementById('first-form')
    if ( !!form ) {
        // event
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
            // get entires
            let object = {}
            object.name = document.getElementById('first-name').val;
            object.lastname = document.getElementById('last-name').val;
            object.cpf = document.getElementById('cpf').val;
            object.tel = document.getElementById('tel').val;
            object.mail = document.getElementById('mail').val
            // save to storage (local or session)
            localStorage.setItem('YOUR_ID_FOR_THIS_FORM', JSON.stringify(object));
        }, false);
    }
</script>
```

Após salvar você pode redirecionar, avisar que foi concluído, etc...

Em uma "nova" (outra) página você deve verificar se a entrada existe e caso exista recuperara os dados.

**exemplo: (página 2)**

```
<!-- HTML Fragment -->
<script>
    // check
    if ( localStorage.getItem('YOUR_ID_FOR_THIS_FORM') ) {
        // parse (transforme a string para um objeto javascript)
        let object = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('YOUR_ID_FOR_THIS_FORM'));
        // use...
    }
</script>
```

Apertir deste ponto podes usar todas as entradas salvas no objeto... vale resaltar a  necessidade de criar sua própria validação para que o conteúdo salvo na primeira página não seja nulo ou diferente do propósito.

Comment: ok, assim que conseguir testar aviso se deu certo. vlws